# Flutter- Fetch data from the Firestore and use it in a FormBuilderDropdown

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

My Web application requires me to read the data from the Firestore and display these fields as values to the dropdownbutton with a checkbox against each of these values. This dropdown will be used in Formbuilder. This is to ensure that multiple values can be selected from a dropdown.  it looks something like this. Can I get some help on this?

[image: example]

```
Widget _buildFormBuilderForm() {
return Column(
children: <Widget>[
FormBuilder(
key: _fbKey,
child: Expanded(
   child: Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
     child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           Row(
             children: <Widget>[
               Expanded(
                 child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: 
                         Firestore.instance.collection("collection") 
                          .snapshots(),
                         builder: (context, snapshot) {
                         if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                return new Text("Please wait");
                                return new FormBuilderDropdown(
                                       initialValue: dropdownvalue,
                                       hint: new Text("Select 
                                                  dropdownvalue"),
                                       attribute: 'dropdownvalue',
                                       decoration: 
                              InputDecoration(labelText:"dropdown"),
                                       items: 
                       snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot 
                       document) {
                             for(int i = 0; i <document.data.length; i++){
                               print(document.data['Name']);
                               return new DropdownMenuItem(
                               value: document.data['Name'],
                               child: new 
                             Text(document.data['Name'].toString()),
                                );
                        }
                   }).toList(),

              onChanged: (value) {
                   print(value);
                   setState(() {
                     dropdownvalue = value;
                     });
                    },
                  );
                }),
               ),
              ),
             ],
            ),
           ]
         ),
      )))
     ],
   );
 }
```

Comment: do you need help in creating the ui or connecting to firebase..? What have you tried so far. Can you share some code so that we can help you.

Comment: I have edited the question. I need help with creating the UI. Each value of the dropdown should also have checkbox against it. I tried adding a checkbox, but looks like FormBuilder does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

Since your example involves firebase stream which is not accessible for me, I providing a generic solution. There is a widget called `FormBuilderCheckboxList` from the FormsBuilder package which might be helpful for you. You might still have workout the laying out part according to your needs.

**Solution 1:**

1. Define a `List<String>` variable to hold the choices user makes in your widget. say

```dart
// hold the options user selects.
List<String> options = [];
```

2. Use the FormBuilder package to create a `FormBuilderDropdown` and with a single `DropdownmenuItem` and a new `FormBuilderCheckboxList` widget as its child and assign the `options` list as `initialValue` and `value` of the `DropdownmenuItem`.

```dart
FormBuilderDropdown(
    attribute: "My Language",
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Laguage"),
    // set it as initial value
    initialValue: options,
    hint: Text('Select Language'),
    validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
    items: [
      DropdownMenuItem(
        // set it as the value of the drop down.
        value: options,
```

3. Use the `onChanged` attribute to capture the choices user selects and add it to the `options` list.

```dart
 onChanged: (values) {                            
   options.clear();
   values.forEach((e) => options.add(e as String));
   setState(() {});
 }
```

**Solution 2:**

1. Use an `ExpansionTile` instead of a dropdown to handle the user selection independently. But you will loose the functionality of closing the menu when use clicks outside the list which is available in a dropdown.

[image]

An example with both the solution included.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() {
    return MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var data;
  bool autoValidate = true;
  bool readOnly = false;
  bool showSegmentedControl = true;
  List<String> options = [];
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FormBuilder Example'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            FormBuilder(
              // context,
              key: _fbKey,
              // autovalidate: true,
              initialValue: {
                'movie_rating': 3,
              },
              readOnly: false,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  // Solution 1
                  FormBuilderDropdown(
                    attribute: "My Language",
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Laguage"),
                    initialValue: options,
                    hint: Text('Select Language'),
                    validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
                    items: [
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: options,
                        child: FormBuilderCheckboxList(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "The language of my people"),
                          attribute: "languages",
                          initialValue: options,
                          options: [
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Dart"),
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Kotlin"),
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Java"),
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Swift"),
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Objective-C"),
                          ],
                          onChanged: (values) {
                            options.clear();
                            values.forEach((e) => options.add(e as String));
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  // Solution 2
                  ExpansionTile(
                    title: Text('My Language'),
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: FormBuilderCheckboxList(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "The language of my people"),
                          attribute: "languages",
                          initialValue: options,
                          options: [
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Dart"),
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Kotlin"),
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Java"),
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Swift"),
                            FormBuilderFieldOption(value: "Objective-C"),
                          ],
                          onChanged: (values) {
                            options.clear();
                            values.forEach((e) => options.add(e as String));
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you @abhliash. I tried what you suggested. But in the FormBuilderFieldOption, the value should be read from the  Firestore. These values are actually document id's of a particular collection in the Firestore.

Comment: You can change the logic as you prefer. Instead hardcoded formbuilderoption you can map the firestore response and build them.